# Under what conditions would lightning channels be force closed automatically?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, core-lightning, eclair

I suspect this depends heavily on the implementation, but maybe someone can shed light on the circumstances that would lead an implementation to force close a channel automatically.

[A user asked this on stacker.news](https://stacker.news/items/17752) but I know all the wizards are on here.

> Nobody in the right mind will force close a channel manually, without a reason. We all do that cooperative close, if a peer is still online and we really need to close that channel.
>
> But automated force closing are really frustrating.
>
> Let's make a list here of all situations, considerations, reasons, causes etc that a channel will be automatically force close and also if you know what steps to do to avoid them.
>
> We have many LND nodes with this situation, few CLN and even fewer Eclair nodes.
> Possible causes:
>
> - some incompatibility between LN implementations ?
> - different CLTV delta settings between peers?
> - too many HTLC on the fly for long time?
> - a minimum time a node can be offline?
> - too many commit changes for a channel in a certain time?
> - bad reconnectivity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering from the perspective of the node that triggers the force-close:

1. Outgoing HTLC times out (i.e., peer doesn't settle/fail in time, which can happen if the peer is offline/unreachable)

   1. There are plenty of special cases, including bugs, though. One fun example: on a payment A-B-C-... where I'm A, node C drops dead. The HTLC between B and C times out, B force-closes. The force-close transaction doesn't confirm in time (because B doesn't bump the fees), so the HTLC between A and B also runs into a time out and A force-closes the channel.
2. Bugs like https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/issues/4649
3. Incoming HTLC times out (I don't know the specifics, but I've seen force-closes where my peer's force-close transaction contained an HTLC that my force-close transaction doesn't have)
4. Peer asks for force-close (recovery mode, "hey, I lost my channel state, please be so kind and broadcast your most recent force-close tx, kthxbye")
5. Trivial: You trigger the force-close manually

Comment: Is there a way to upgrade your system, which generally takes time and rarely goes without a hitch, without resulting in a bunch of force closures? Disable all channels? Anything?

Comment: Usually, a couple of hours of downtime are OK. You can wait until your node doesn't have a pending HTLC to reduce the disk. In the past 5 years only did that for major updates, not simple reboots.